# How do I differ position-x of two components on the same line?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Heres my code :

```
<input id="homebutton" type="image" style="display:inline" src="home.png" name="saveform" class="btTxt submit ml-3" onclick="location.href='home.html'"/>
<h5 id="theatrename" style="display:inline" class="text-center mt-5">name</h5>
```

So I managed to place the 'homebutton' and the 'name' on the same line, but I want the 'homebutton' to be placed at the left while the 'name' to be placed on the text-center.

I've already tried `class="text-center"` as like in the code above but it doesn't seem to work :/
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to force align an element an option would be `float` property.
See this example bellow.

next option would be absolutely positioned. but be careful to padding in absolute position element to be sure it does not overlay the input.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 25px;
}

#homebutton {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: 25px
}

#theatrename {
  padding: 0 25px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: inline;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="homebutton" type="image" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/69/69524.png" name="saveform" class="btTxt submit ml-3" onclick="location.href='home.html'" />
  <h5 id="theatrename" class="text-center mt-5">name</h5>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried it but 'name' doesn't seem to be placed in the centre of the entire screen but it's in the centre of the area excluding the 'homebutton'.
idk how to explain this but its kinda placed a bit towards the right from the centre?